# Where to store JWT token in client side and how to secure it?

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I am using node js for validating user and sending back JWT token. I am using Angular 6.0 for front end. My question is Where to store this token at client side? and How to secure this token if I am using localstorage at client side?

Answer (score 2):

sort flow:

1, store refresh_token at cookie with httpOnly (mean u need a backend sever to stored it)

2, each time your client go to website(even reload, etc...), u need get access_token from back-end and return it to front-end. So this thing can prevent XSS attack but CSRF is another story.